# Assertion failure in UITableView configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm not sure where the error is here, having looked at other similar issues. 
I received an Assertion failure.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

I think it is something simple but hope someone can help.

Below is my code:

```
#import "StockMarketViewController.h"

@interface StockMarketViewController ()

@end


@implementation StockMarketViewController
@synthesize ShareNameText, ShareValueText, AmountText;
@synthesize shares, shareValues;


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return [shares count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];



    NSString *currentValue = [shareValues objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel]setText:currentValue];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Please update your question to mark which line is causing the exception. If you don't know, set breakpoints and step through the code until you find the exact line.

Comment: Well i am new to xcode so i am unsure with these things, but in this case, there are no errors appear, and program runs but crashes when I select the relevant page? So i dont know which line is the error if that makes sense? I would presume  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Comment: Is there actually a cell with the (case-sensitive) identifier @"cell"?

Comment: if not would that cause an issue? As I said i am very new to this, and was using tutorials to assist me and that was part of the code they used.

Comment: Do not forget to change the property of the Content > Dynamic Prototypes in the UITableView.

Comment: You get this assertion when you return **nil** to `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 108, accepted):

you are never creating a cell, you just try to reuse a dequeued cell. but as you never created one, there is none.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *currentValue = [shareValues objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel]setText:currentValue];
    return cell;
}
```

or try (only iOS 6+)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *currentValue = [shareValues objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel]setText:currentValue];
    return cell;
}
```

---

from UITableView.h

```
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;  // Used by the delegate to acquire an already allocated cell, in lieu of allocating a new one.
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier 
                           forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered
```

`-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will always need a check, if a cell was returned, while
`-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` can instantiate new one.

Comment: What he's doing is perfectly okay.  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will create the cell if it does not exist.

Comment: @sapi not so, it will only create a cell if you are using storyboard prototypes or have registered a nib or class for reuse.

Comment: True, but if he's following a tutorial it's extremely likely that he's using prototypes (or is trying to, but hasn't defined one).  That's also what the default code stubs for `UITableViewController` expect.

Comment: @sapi, you mean - (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered

Comment: I did indeed mean that.  Sorry about the mistake, maybe I should get some sleep :)

Comment: If I wanted to display a value beside a share price, what way do i go about that?

Comment: either use a appropriate style or create a custom cell. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Comment: @JasonTaylor - one thing to be aware of in following a book or tutorial on iOS/Objective-C/Xcode ... things change very quickly and books/tutorials in this area can become outdated on almost a yearly basis. As noted in the answer/comments above iOS6 has a slightly different way of handling UITableViewCells. It's not always possible to find an up-to-date version of a given tutorial, but whenever you can it will save you a lot of grief. (Spoken as someone with a shelf of Cocoa/Objective-C books he planned to get to someday only to find out they were obsolete when "someday" finally came.)

Comment: Thanks, I have inserted a newsfeed table, a shares table, both using plists. I need to include share value in share table and depending on the severity of the newsfeed then this share value will change accordingly. I am doing this for my final year project at University, and there are no lecturers who have xcode knowledge so I appreciate any advice that i can get as Im alone on this and only started xcode at christmas time. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: One caveat that happened with me was I realized that I was programmatically newing up a controller. What I needed to do instead was use UIStoryboard to instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier to access it from the storyboard. Only then did it have the table, prototype cells, etc.

Answer (score 13):

If you have not defined a prototype cell with the identifier `@"cell"` in Storyboard, you will get an assertion error when you attempt to dequeue it.

You can fix this by setting the `Identifier` property on the prototype cell (select the cell and set that attribute in the right hand panel).

Comment: This might sound shocking, but i am not using storyboards? Is there anything else i can do? And why are people voting down my question, advice how to improve? For its tough starting this language from a non programming background. Thanks

Comment: If you're not using Storyboards, see @jrturton's comment on vikingosegundo's answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I had accidentally set the "restoration i.d." in the identity inspector to "cell" rather than the "identifier" in the attributes inspection.

Answer (score 7):

A very silly mistake i had done was

i didn't put the UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource after the controller class name like
my class code was
**class TagsViewController: UIViewController**

it should have **class TagsViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource**

May be one of you is facing due to this all other code was ok.

Comment: Thanks, did same mistake. Solved !

Comment: Welsome @HardikDarji

Answer (score 0):

You need to call "initWithStyle" in custom TableViewCell and initialise  the objects again.

Example: ProductTableViewCell.m file

```
@implementation ProductTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])
    {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        _titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(70, 0, 320, 60))];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_titleLabel];
   }
   return self;
}
```

In the main implementation file

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
    ProductTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"productTableViewCell"];
    NSDictionary *dic = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        dic = [_filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        dic = [_originalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.titleLabel.text = [dic objectForKey: @"title"];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I managed to find the fault. I had an array for the segues and view titles:

```
NSArray *MMTitles= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MainMenu",@"viewIt",@"viewNots",@"MyProfile",@"Settings",@"Instructions",@"Help", nil];
NSArray *MMSegues=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MainMenu",@"MyProfileSegue",@"viewNotSegue",@"MyProfileSegue",@"SettingsTableViewSegue",@"InstructionsViewSegue",@"HelpViewSegue", nil];

self.menuItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:MMTitles,MMSegues, nil];
```

I then used this array as the datasource for my table. The error I was receiving was due to the fact that I didn't in fact had the `HelpViewSegue` declared in my Storyboard when I instantiated the VC:

```
    vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: [[self.menuItems objectAtIndex:1]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Pretty trivial, but it was pretty frustrating! Hope this helped.

Answer (score -2):

In the below code you have written `@"cell"` (written with a small `c`), but you have to use `@"Cell"` (`C` must be capital).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Comment: add index path also